# How NASM function receives parameter?

Tags: c, nasm

So I am very new into NASM, and found a tutorial on a website with an example like this:

```
        global  maxofthree
        section .text
maxofthree:
        mov     rax, rdi                ; result (rax) initially holds x
        cmp     rax, rsi                ; is x less than y?
        cmovl   rax, rsi                ; if so, set result to y
        cmp     rax, rdx                ; is max(x,y) less than z?
        cmovl   rax, rdx                ; if so, set result to z
        ret                             ; the max will be in rax
```

This NASM file simply comparing 3 given numbers and select the biggest one among them. I run it in C file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int64_t maxofthree(int64_t, int64_t, int64_t);

int main() {
    printf("%ld\n", maxofthree(5, -4234, -5000));

    return 0;
}
```

The program of course runs pretty well and return correctly the biggest number between 3 numbers.

So now, I would like to know how to comparing between 10 numbers, and what I have thought I should do is using more register, but there are only 8 registers so I dont think getting register for each number is a good way.

Also, I tried putting the register in alphabetical order, e.g:

```
mov     rax, rbx
cmp     rax, rcx                
cmovl   rax, rcx                
cmp     rax, rdx                
cmovl   rax, rdx
```

But the result returned is just a random number and I honestly don't undestand why.

This language is so confusing and I really grateful for any help from experts.

Comment: Usually if you have more parameters than registers the parameters are pushed on the stack instead. However you need to check the documentation about calling convention to see the details

Comment: `int64_t val[10] = { ... }; printf("%ld\n", maxofthree( maxofthree( maxofthree(val[0], val[1], val[2]), maxofthree(val[3], val[4], val[5]), maxofthree(val[6], val[7], val[8]) ), maxofthree(val[9], INT64_MIN, INT64_MIN), INT64_MIN) );`